# Detach my Pokemon Go account from my Google Login

Tags: pokemon-go

I made the mistake of starting a Pokemon Go account with the "use your Google login option." This is a problem because my kids want to play using my Pokemon Go account, but from other devices (i.e. not my smartphone). I don't want them to be logging into my Google account from other devices.

Is there any option to convert my Pokemon Go account to a "normal" login that doesn't use Google for authentication?

Comment: There's currently no way to achieve what you want. Your options are starting a fresh account or giving up your Google account.

Comment: Possibly worth noting as well that the 'normal' login is through Pokemon Trainers Club, which has frequently encountered issues to the point that many PTC users have begged for a way to switch their logins to Google...

Answer (score 8):

Since facebook login was introduced, there is a way to switch an existing account (of any type) to a different Google Account (or facebook profile). This way, you can disconnect the existing Pokemon Go account from your "real" Google account. Here's how:

1. Create a new facebook profile. Be creative, it just needs to look real.
2. Create a new Google account to use for the Pokemon Go account and add it to your device.
3. While in game, go to Settings and connect your facebook profile from Step 1.
4. Disconnect your old Google account.
5. Connect your new Google account. (Unless you want to use the facebook profile for the future.)
6. Disconnect the facebook profile (optional).

This will essentially replace your old Google account with a new one so your kids can log into the account on a different device using a "burner" Google account.

Answer (score 7):

Or you could set up a separate email for your children to use to play it. You could still be able to manage the email either directly or as an extension of your current email. I would recommend something like this because you can continue to play along with them :)

Comment: That's the only way, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Close the game. Turn off the Wifi on your phone, then Open Pokemon Go.

Once it opens, it will say "Login failed. *Try with a different account*"

Click on "*Try with a different account*", and that will log you out from that phone, and next time you open Pokemon Go, you'll have the fresh install "Returning Player" and "New Player" options. Don't worry, your account is not lost, if you log back in as "Returning player", you will get back to exactly where you were.

On the fresh login interface, you have "New Player" and "Returning Player".

If you choose "New Player", options are :

- Facebook
- Google
- Pokemon Trainer Club

If you choose "Returning Player", options are:

- Facebook
- Google
- Pokemon Trainer Club
- Niantic Kids

You could look into the Pokmon Trainer club login option.

Comment: You can also simply log out in the game's settings. This doesn't help with the original question though, which wasn't about logging into a new account, but moving the account over to a different Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to you google settings (in a browser or so) and search for the point "connected apps & sites" under "sign in & security". You should be able to manage your apps and remove their access. This should have the effect you want to achieve. 
If there isn't an entry from Pokemon Go or it didn't work, than you can also use the sign-out function. You will find it in the Pokemon Go app in the settings. You can view them when clicking on the red-white pokeball in the middle of the map-screen, and then on the upper-right

Comment: Pokemon Go is not connected to Google. It merely uses the Google account on the device to identify the Pokemon Go account, which is entirely seperate from the Google account, so it won't show up in the connected apps & sites. However, this also means logging into a Pokemon Go account is only possible on a device logged into the corresponding Google account, which is what OP doesn't want.

Comment: ^ Above is true for android, iOS signs you in through your browser

Comment: @scenia I wonder if this poses a security risk. E.g. somebody could hack Pokemon Go to impersonate someone else's google account if he has his email. Since Pokemon Go does a one-time check only in the beginning and then caches the fact that this person is authenticated. Someone tampering with this cache could come across as logged in as someone else.

Comment: @WadihM. I don't see how this would help stealing a Google account. Worst case, someone could hack the cache to fake being logged into Pokemon Go and steal that account, but since the Google login is only used to authenticate for Pokemon Go, the security risk is only to Pokemon Go. The Google account is permanently connected to the device anyway, so anyone who can hack the Pokemon Go caching can probably also just hack the Google account caching in the first place.